# Compare two strings and return the difference as 0s and 1s efficiently in Python

Tags: python

I have a set of strings as student answers for a test and the answer key.

```
Student answers: ABDEDCAB
Answer key:      ABCCCABB
```

I would like to return a list with 0s and 1s, 0 when the student missed the answer and 1 for a correct answer.

```
Return = [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1]
```

The problem here is not to find a solution, but an efficient one. Each student has 180 answers and there are 6 million students and any iteration that I try to do is taking forever.

```
%%time
for j in dfw['CN_respostas'].head(10000).index:
    lista = []
    for i in range(len(dfw['CN_respostas'][j])):
        if dfw['CN_respostas'][0][i] == dfw['CN_gabarito'][0][i]:
            lista.append(1)
        else:
            lista.append(0)
```

Only 10000 iterations in 45 answers gives this result:

```
CPU times: user 14.8 s, sys: 396 ms, total: 15.2 s
Wall time: 17.6 s
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `6MM`?

Comment: 6 Millions students

Comment: Your issue are the 6 million students, not the 180 answers. Optimising the string comparison is a red herring. Optimise the student scan, e.g. via multiprocessing or vectorisation.

Comment: Can you show the structure of your dataframe?

Comment: On a side-note: If there are 6 million users, but only 180 answers you could reduce the work of the code by reducing duplicates. E.g. find all UNIQUE answers first, compare only the unique anwswers with the solution and then join them back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward (and, in my testing, the fastest) way to do this may just be a list comprehension using `zip`:

```
import time

a = 'ABDEDCAB'
b = 'ABCCCABB'


start = time.time()
for i in range(10000000):
    c = [x == y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

This runs in about 9.5 seconds on my machine to do the comparison of 8 answers 10 million times.

*Edit: I've now tested with 6 million sets of 180 answers and got a run time of about 75 seconds on my machine.*

Comment: Thanks Kemp. Would this work for data in a pandas dataframe?

Comment: @FláviodeFalcão I'm not very familiar with pandas unfortunately, and I wrote this answer before the edit that added your example code. but I can't see there being a huge problem. Worth benchmarking at least.

Comment: @FláviodeFalcão For reference, I've now tested this approach with 6 million sets of 180 answers and got a run time of about 75 seconds on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip for this:

```
s1 = 'ABDEDCAB'
s2 = 'ABCCCABB'

[int(x==y) for x,y in zip(s1,s2)]
# Out[70]: [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

To apply in a dataframe:

```
def func(s1,s2):
    return [int(x==y) for x,y in zip(s1,s2)]

df.apply(lambda row: func(row['solution'], row['answer']), axis=1)
```